# Receber dados do usuário

Tags: python

Fiz um algoritmo para realizar cálculos de estatística, gostaria de colocar duas opções para o usuário:

Primeiro, fazer os cálculos com dados já amocados dentro do algoritmo

Segundo, fazer com que o usuário digite seus próprios dados para fazer os cálculos,

A primeira opção está funcionando, agora a segunda opção não, poderia ver onde estar meu erro.

```
import statistics

def inputsmenu():



    print("Digite 1 para Dados do Sistema, Digite 2 para Dados do Usuario: \n")



    DADOS_USUARIO = int(input("Digite os Dados:\n"))
    menu(DADOS_USUARIO)



def menu(x):
    if (x == 1):
        DADOS_SISTEMAS = [10,20,30,40,50,60,5,87,100,65,84,24,44,5,0,68]
    else:
        DADOS_USUARIO=[]
    print("Qual calculo estatistico você deseja fazer? \n")
    print ("1 - Mediana")
    print ("2 - Moda")
    print ("3 - Min")
    print ("4 - Max")
    print ("5 - Media")
    print ("6 - Desvio padrão")
    print ("7 - Variancia")

    escolha = int(input())

    if escolha == 1:
        print("\nA mediana dos Dados foi: ", statistics.median(DADOS_SISTEMA))
        pass
    elif escolha == 2:
        print("A moda dos Dados foi: ", statistics.mode(DADOS_SISTEMAS))
        pass
    elif escolha == 3:
        print("O numero minimo dos Dados foi: ", min(DADOS_SISTEMAS))
        pass
    elif escolha == 4:
        print("O numero maximo dos Dados foi: ", max(DADOS_SISTEMAS))
        pass
    elif escolha == 5:
        print("A media dos Dados foi: ", statistics.mean(DADOS_SISTEMAS))
        pass
    elif escolha == 6:
        print("O Desvio padrao foi: ", statistics.stdev(DADOS_SISTEMAS))
        pass
    elif escolha == 7:
        print("A variancia foi: ", statistics.variance(DADOS_SISTEMAS))
        pass



if __name__ == '__main__':
    inputsmenu()
```

Answer (score 1):

[TL;DR](https://repl.it/@sidonduarte/python-statistcs1)

Seu erro é que vc não implementou a segunda opcao, vou deixar um exemplo abaixo, um pouco diferente do seu, mas é só vc adaptar. Para ser mais simples não estou fazendo consistencias do tipo ver se o usuario digitou como deveria digitar, etc.

```
import statistics
tipo = input('Escolha (1) para sistema ou (2) para seus dados (usuário)')

if tipo=='2':
    dados = input('entre com os dados separados por virgulas: ').split(',')
else:
    dados = [10,20,30,40,50,60,5,87,100,65,84,24,44,5,0,68]

# Convertendo para inteiros    
idados = [int(d) for d in dados]    

# Funcoes estatísticas
functions = {'1': statistics.median, '2': statistics.mode, '3': min,  '4': max, '5': statistics.mean, 
             '6': statistics.stdev, '7': statistics.variance }

# A função que o usuário deverá escolher
calculo = input('1 - Mediana, 2 - Moda, 3 - Min, 4 - Max, 5 - Media, 6 - Desvio padrão, 7 - Variancia' )

print('Resultado: ', functions[calculo](idados))
```

[Veja funcionando no repl.it](https://repl.it/@sidonduarte/python-statistcs1)